# A javascript to implement base64 image encoding and write result to text file

Tags: javascript, html

How can modify following code:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var openFile = function(event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            var dataURL = reader.result;
            //var output = document.getElementById('output');
            //output.src = dataURL;

            var pngData = dataURL.split('base64,')[1];
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pngData;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I've a static image filename in my local path?

And how can write the result in a new textfile?

Comment: You don't have access to the file system in JS ... use localStorage instead ... see below.

Comment: You can however *create* a file that is downloaded by the user, but why on earth would you use B64 for that? If you're trying to store the image on the server, you'll need serverside code, and if you're trying to store it in the browser, use the proposed solution below.

Comment: @Domenico - do you want it save to the client or server ?

Comment: I'm using appinventor to my android app. I'm not a programmer...., now I'm doing a app that send a mail with attachement, so I need a base64 encoding. Appinventor hasn't this capability and so I'm searching a workaround by javascript that run on html page. My Idea is to run a html page that call my Image file and give me the result of encoding or the file name where is stored the image encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Just save it to `localStorage` in the onload callback:

```
reade.onload = function (event) {

    // modify for base64
    localSorage.namespace_file_name_ext = event.target.result;
```